# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value using Api json function mvc

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Hello i want to Send OTP Using Api when send show this error on this line :

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(result);
```

Anyone can tell me what is the issue in this line?

Error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

```
 public JsonResult SOTP()
        {
            int otpValue = new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
            var status = "";
            try
            {
                string recipient = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecipientNumber"].ToString();
                string APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"].ToString();

                string message = "Your OTP Number is " + otpValue + " ( Sent By : Technotips-Ashish )";
                String encodedMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(message);

                using (var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues("https://control.txtlocal.co.uk/send/", new NameValueCollection(){

                                         {"apikey" , APIKey},
                                         {"numbers" , recipient},
                                         {"message" , encodedMessage},
                                         {"sender" , "TXTLCL"}});

                    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);

                    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(result);

                    status = jsonObject["status"].ToString();

                    Session["CurrentOTP"] = otpValue;
                }


                return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw (e);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your json is probably invalid. Could you please edit your question and paste the content of your json string (variable result)?

Comment: Whole file show in result. i cannot share whole file data because to much line of code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
                    
          
            <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
           
</html>

Comment: That's HTML, not json - that's why `JObject.Parse` fails.

Comment: Sir How can i resolve this Problem ?

Comment: Was the API supposed to return json? Try to understand why it is returning HTML

Comment: Read the HTML that you get back. It may have a clue, like 404 not found or 401 unauthorized, etc.

Comment: Is this line is ok : byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues("https://control.txtlocal.co.uk/send/", new NameValueCollection() @Rui Jarimba

Comment: @JournalTrends I have no idea what is that API supposed to do, or what should be returned. Have you checked the HTTP status of the response, as suggested by @Crowcoder? Is it Ok (status code 200) or an error status?

Comment: @JournalTrends we cannot know if that line is "ok". We would have to be familiar with that particular API and also know what values you are using. What does the HTML say? I know it's not pretty to read but it should have an indication what went wrong. Also, a different client like `HttpClient` will give more detailed response so maybe don't use `WebClient`